# Changing display name in Model to show in response

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, webapi

I am looking for a way to change the display Name of a property in Model so that the same would be reflect in the response body in swagger.

I tried using `DisplayName` attribute for the field but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
[DisplayName("Fucntion ID")]
public string FunctionId { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Function Description")]
public string FunctionDEscription { get; set; }
```

[image]

Is there any other way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use asp.net core 3.x and asp.net 5,you could use `[JsonPropertyName("Fucntion ID")]` which is in `System.Text.Json`.

If you use asp.net core 2.x,you could use `[JsonProperty("Fucntion ID")]` which is in `Json.NET`.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=netcore-3.1

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer-

Used  `[JsonPropertyName("Fucntion ID")]`  instead of `[DisplayName("Fucntion ID")]`